# CH34x driver/kext installation OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, driver, kernel-extension

I'm trying to get the drivers on OSX Sierra running. But no result.

My research got me to the following sites:
https://github.com/adrianmihalko/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver
https://tzapu.com/ch340-ch341-serial-adapters-macos-sierra/
https://blog.sengotta.net/signed-mac-os-driver-for-winchiphead-ch340-serial-bridge/
http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_MAC_ZIP.html (announced as latest version)

Before i've tried to install them i tried this while i was in recovery mode ( restart with ⌘ + R ).

```
csrutil enable --without kext
```

Afterwards i've tried to install the drivers.

This didn't worked out so i've disabled csrutil in recovery mode too.

```
csrutil disable
```

**My steps for installing each driver**

*While csrutil is disabled.*

1. Remove the old driver
2. Install the new one

**Removing the driver:**

```
$ sudo su
$ find / | grep usbserial/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext
...
/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext/Contents
/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature
/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext/Contents/Info.plist
/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext/Contents/MacOS
/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext/Contents/MacOS/usbserial
/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext/Contents/Resources
/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext/Contents/Resources/en.lproj
/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
...
$ rm -rf /Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext
$ find / | grep wch
...
/private/var/db/receipts/com.wch.ch34xinstall.mykextdir.pkg.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.wch.ch34xinstall.mykextdir.pkg.plist
...
$ rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/com.wch.*
$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

**Installing the new one:**

- just installing the .pkg
- reboot
- searching for the driver in /dev
- there was **no driver** listed

Did i missed something?

Edit: I found out the kext is not loaded. But why?
[image: kext not loaded]

Edit2: Now i loaded the kext but the serial driver is not showing in /dev.

```
tim:~$ sudo kextload -b com.wch.usbserial
Password:
tim:~$
```

[image: kext loaded]

And it is not showing in kextstats.

```
tim:~$ kextstat | grep com.wch.usbserial
tim:~$
```

But it can be found.

```
tim:~$ kextfind -b com.wch.usbserial
/System/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext
/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext
```

Maybe just the kext is not working?

```
tim:~$ sudo kextutil -b com.wch.usbserial
Password:
Warnings:
    Dependency lacks appropriate value for OSBundleRequired and may not be availalble during early boot:
        com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily - Safe Boot
```

Comment: This answer also helped me to allow Cubase on High Sierra to see the Novation USB driver, which was otherwise blocked by the OSX System Integrity Protection (SIP) restrictions. The post above and this page which details how to disable SIP: http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/ may help others to allow Cubase (and other Audio tools) to use drivers for legacy audio/midi hardware that do not have drivers updated and signed to be compatible with the OSX SIP restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's working**

I moved the SiLabsUSBDriver ( made a backup to my desktop ), plugged in the the device and i was able to use it.

**The serial driver didn't showed up in /dev/ when no devices with a serial USB port was plugged in!**

See the following screenshot for more information about the driver.
[image: SiLabsUSBDriver screenshot]